# Number of surjective functions from the cardinals of the sets

Tags: combinatorics, discrete-mathematics

We have $\left|A\right|=k$ and $\left|B\right|=n$. How many surjective functions $\:f\::\:A\to \:B$ exist? Provide a demonstration.

Where $\left|A\right|$ is the cardinal of A.

How to solve this?

Comment: Well, I know that in a surjective functions, for every number in the codomain, we need to have a number in a domain so that f(x) = y, where y is in the codomain and x is in the domain.

Comment: But I don't really know how to go about solving the exercise, and then demonstrate it. I'm guessing I need to find some sort of formula to determine the number of functions that are surjective, based on the sets' cardinals.

Comment: @BrianO: I just upvoted your answer to the earlier question, so you can now vote to close this one.

Comment: @BrianM.Scott Thanks much, I will.